# Blazor Component changing for all loggedin-in users When using Blazor Web server

Tags: blazor

Application is using blazor web server. When a user enters that section and changes the view by clicking a link, the view for all users will change to that corresponding view.

e.g. User A is viewing pageA, User B goes to page A and then clicks a link that would change the component to pageB. User A and User B are now pageB.

Project is on an IIS Server

Please help me out on this issue

I have tried using **services.AddScoped** but still the same issue.

Comment: This issue got by removing func delegates from the code